# What's the proper place to call InitCommonControlsEx()?

Tags: c, winapi, windows-10, initialization, controls

I'm learning WINAPI, so I'm dealing with tab control, which requires to call `InitCommonControlsEx()` but where's the proper place to call it? when `WM_CREATE` message is received in the windows callback procedure? or before the main loop `while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))` or somewhere else? I've seen all those approches I mentioned being used, I'm not quite sure which one is correct.

Comment: You *must* call it before attempting to use the first control that requires it. You *can* call it once for all, or multiple times for individual control classes. How and where to do it is your choice, as long as it follows the *must* rule.

Comment: Second sentence from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-initcommoncontrolsex): "An application must call this function before creating a common control."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best place to call it is once at program startup, such as in `WinMain()`, before you start creating your UI Windows.

Comment: even before `RegisterClass()` is a good practice?

Comment: @Jack at least before the `CreateWindow/Ex` call for the 1st window that uses any controls from that library